# UITabBar doesn't seem to accept my language settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, localization

I'm having some difficulty rendering my UITabBar in the language I want. I'm developing an app for the dutch market, so I want dutch to be the only language used within my app.

The app is a tab bar application, with more than 5 tabs, so the UITabBarController has its moreNavigationController displayed.

However, it keeps displaying the texts 'More' and 'Configure' instead of the dutch words 'Meer' and 'Configureer'. Nothing I have tried seems to fix this issue, I tried:

1. Changed my iPhone's language to dutch -> nope, still got 'More' and 'Configure'
2. Set my apps default language to dutch in my AppDelegate like this:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       @autoreleasepool
       {
           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nl", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
           return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
       }
   }
   ```

But still no luck...

Number 2 would be my preferred option, as I want my app to always display dutch texts, regardless of system defaults.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Dutch to `CFBundleLocalizations` in your info.plist.

Comment: Wow, now that was embarrassing. I added CFBundleLocalizations to my App-Info.plist with only item 'nl' and it works :)